Stack Trace returned when forwarded without headers set
I have a system with two servers, API server and Core server. They both run Java applications in Wildfly. The requests come into the API server, which also has nginx running. The requests are proxy-pass to the applications running in the localhost or to the other server. When the requests forwarded to the Core server without the X-Forwarded-For proxy header has an error the stack trace is returned, however with the header set only the Error code is returned. I'm not sure why this is happening and hoping someone can explain it.

Please provide the stack trace
